# 'Using' Keyword Not Functional

Tags: c#

I have a file `Dictionary.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Dictionary
{
    public SortedDictionary<string, List<WordForm>> wordList { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Word> dictionary { get; set; }

    public struct WordForm
    {
        public string rootWord { get; set; }
        public string formIdentifier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'SortedDictionary' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Midlife\Dictionary.cs

To my knowledge, `using System.Collections.Generic;` allows me to use `SortedDictionary`. But it's throwing an error, and I have no idea why. I can use `Dictionary` just fine. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure? Your code compiles fine on my computer. Could be coming this error somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried changing your class name from Dictionary to something unique?

Comment: Tried renaming the class `Dictionary` to `Dict` to avoid the name collision; it did not help. @zaheer-ahmed, tried wrapping the class in a namespace `languageSet`; this also did not help. If it compiles fine for other people, then I wonder what else could be causing the problem... any ideas? This is a newly-created project...

Comment: Aren't you, by any chance, compiling against .NET 1.1? It doesn't know SortedDictionary.

Comment: `App.config` shows .NET **4.5**, so I doubt it's compiling against *1.1*...

Comment: You should change the name not only to avoid name collision (which didn't help) but so you can tell the two classes apart. Your code will be easier to read. Generally, using common API names is not very *friendly* to who will have to read the code.

Comment: @pid, I agree with that. It's just kind of unfortunate that my data is *actually* a dictionary, and the API *isn't*. In any case, I'll rename it because it could become very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SortedDictionary` is in `System.Collections.Generic`, but you need to make sure you've got a reference to `System.dll`, as that's the assembly that contains the class.

Although `Dictionary` is in `System.Collections.Generic` it lives in a different assembly, `mscorlib.dll` which has been referenced by every project since C# 1.0

To see what you're referencing go to the project in the solution explorer. You should see an expandable section called "References". Expand it and see if "System" is listed. If not then right click on "References" and select "Add Reference". A dialog will appear, and in the "Assemblies" section under "Framework" scroll down until you find "System" and make sure that the check box that appears on the left is ticked. This close and rebuild.

Comment: How do I make sure that I have a reference to `System.dll`?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice - I've added more info to the answer

Comment: @GrantWinney, that is exactly what the problem was! Shouldn't the `using` keyword automatically add the needed references during the build process though? At least, that's what would make sense to me I suppose. I don't know why `System` wasn't included in `References`, but the problem is fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice - Adding a `using` can't automatically add the references as namespaces can be split across multiple assemblies, as is the case with `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: @Sean, I suppose that makes sense. And Grant, I didn't delete it, I know that for sure. I did create an 'empty' project in VS 2013, but I'm 99% positive that's how I *usually* create them, and I've never run into that problem before. I guess the error was 'obvious enough'... it said I was missing a reference, I just didn't know what that reference was!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: most users don't start from an empty project.

Comment: Woah, well I didn't know that. I just started C# yesterday, I'm still familiarizing myself with the IDE and the structure of the program :)